# How do I apply an UNINITIALISED class to an object in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, class

I hope this code sample is clear enough about what I'm trying to do.

Note that this is a reduced test case to demonstrate the core trouble that I'm having. I don't want to know how to make this example simpler. I want to know how to stop TypeScript from complaining. I also don't want to use the `any` type.

```
// start with a class
class HelloWorld {
    hello = 'hello'

    world(): string {
        return this.hello + ' world'
    }
}

// Create an interface for an object
interface Greeting {
    Hello: HelloWorld
}

// The interface is applied to an object
// The class is applied to a value inside the object
// Note that it is an UNINITIALISED class
const greet: Greeting = {
    // ERROR: Type 'typeof HelloWorld' is missing the following properties
    // from type 'HelloWorld': hello, world ts(2739)
    Hello: HelloWorld,
}

// Later in the code you initialise it like this
// ERROR: This expression is not constructable.
// Type 'HelloWorld' has no construct signatures.ts(2351)
const greeting = new greet.Hello()

console.log(greeting.world()) // "hello world"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're treating a *normal class* as an *instance's interface* here. It works only for it's instances that are declared using `new` keyword. To properly use class types in interfaces, convert the class to a type or interface, so that the TypeScript will know you're inferring the class itself, instead of it's instances.

Here is how you declare interface for both class and instance of a class

```
interface Greeting {
    // declaring type for the class itself
    Hello: typeof HelloWorld,

    // declaring the type for it's instance
    hello: HelloWorld
}

const greet: Greeting = {
    // Assigning the class itself
    Hello: HelloWorld,

    // Assigning an instances of HelloWorld
    hello: new HelloWorld()
}

const greeting = new greet.Hello()

// `greeting` is now identical to `greet.hello`
```

Comment: Yay! Thank you! :D

Comment: I just wanted to specifically call out that it was an uncalled class because the only answers I could find involved called classes.

Comment: By called classes, do you mean it's instances?

Comment: `new greet.Hello()` is what I call a "called" class. Do I need to rephrase the question?

Comment: Yes. Called class refers to the act of calling the class itself while instance refers to the output of the called class with `new` keyword. I also edit my answer to accommodate both instances and class.

Comment: I've reworded it to say "UNINITIALISED" instead of "UNCALLED" now.

Comment: Updated my answer as well explaining the difference between class inference and instance inference. Hope it will also help others in the future